# Autodesk Viewer double-compressed streams

Tags: autodesk-viewer

When using Autodesk Viewer I'm receiving the error:

> An LMV resource
>   ([redacted]/1/objects_attrs.json.gz)
>   was not uncompressed by the browser. This hurts performance. Check the
>   Content-Encoding header returned by the server and check whether
>   you're getting double-compressed streams. The warning prints only once
>   but it's likely the problem affects multiple resources.

My response headers are as follows:

[image]

Should my response have a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header? Is the Viewer decompressing the files rather than the browser when this error is logged in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the viewer is handling the decompression if you see this warning and this is not desirable performance-wise.

Can you take a look at my article about using a proxy to serve your viewer resources: [Securing your Forge Viewer token behind a proxy](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/securing-your-forge-viewer-token-behind-proxy)

This set the correct content-encoding for gzipped resources (node.js code):

```
function fixContentHeaders (req, res) {

  // DS does not return content-encoding header
  // for gzip and other files that we know are gzipped,
  // so we add it here. The viewer does want
  // gzip files uncompressed by the browser
  if ( EXTENSIONS.gzip.indexOf (path.extname (req.path)) > -1 ) {
    res.set ('content-encoding', 'gzip')
  }

  if ( EXTENSIONS.json.indexOf (path.extname (req.path)) > -1 ){
    res.set ('content-type', 'application/json')
  }
}
```

Also this allows you to serve the files directly from the derivatives service:

```
//This API available from v 2.14 
Autodesk.Viewing.setEndpointAndApi( 
  window.location.origin + '/lmv-proxy', 
 'modelDerivativeV2')
```

Comment: it worths to mention it has changed since then. you can use it with Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.setEndpointAndApi